# Why GTM restirct tag deployment doesnt work

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm currently working on blocking the scripts injected by gtm and I noticed there's a way to add allowlist or blocklist inside datalayer to reach that: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/restrict

But after trying to add the gtm.allowlist/blocklist, it still injects the 3rd party scripts

Anyone who had any experience on that? Many thx

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tried with putting the allowlist before/after the gtm start or using the blocklist instead. None of these works. Is the the right way blocking the script injection from gtm? Or there is better way?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to allow the delivery of a tag is to associate the correct trigger based on the classification of the cookies you assign.

With OneTrust (you are using) the cookie (or the `OnetrustActiveGroups` variable) that contains the information of the accepted cookie classes will contextually contain the values ​​`C0001`, `C0002`, `c0003`, `C0004`, ... If for example the category `C0004` is for cookies may be set through our site by our
advertising partners, to GTM Facebook tags, Ads tags, etc ... you will assign as a trigger the check that in that variable there is that value. If it is present the tag is fired otherwise not.

In this way everything is much more controlled and you leave nothing to chance or to the interpretation of the tool.